# Change private theme for all users to Social Office in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I've managed to import about 600 users from Active Directory using LDAP and I'm trying to set every single user's default private theme to the Social Office theme. Is there a way to select every single user and assign them the Social Office User role? Is this the right way to go about doing this or do I need to delete all the users and re-import them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of import you can use `void com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalServiceUtil.importLayouts(long userId, long groupId, boolean privateLayout, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap, File file);` to update the privateLayout for each user or if you want to update publicPage layout then pass argument privateLayout=false
for reference:check com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalServiceUtil()

Comment: How would I use this? Does this need to go inside a hook? If so what file would I be overwriting?

Comment: " import about 600 users from Active Directory"
are you using the LDAP? or you have built the custom portlet?

Comment: If you are working over LR6.1.1 version then along with user import there is also configuration for group import for individual user, have you tried that ?

Comment: Yes, I've managed to import users and groups from the LDAP authentication screen in Liferay, but their private pages are always set to the Classic theme by default. I want to have their private pages set to another theme by default.